# Can I inspect DLLs arguments in MFC?

Tags: mfc

I would like to ask, can I inspect calls made to dlls inside an MFC based app ?
Can I have a history of calls with method names& arguments values ??
Is there a tool than generates such a report ?

Thanks,
hopeweise

Answer (score 0):

from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264944.aspx#BKMK_CallsAndParameters

When you enable IntelliTrace Events and Call Information, IntelliTrace collects a record of each call entry and exit. On entry, IntelliTrace collects name and value information for each parameter.

Comment: Thanks Sheng, but this feature is supported in Visual Studio Ultimate version, which is very expensive, isn't there an alternative ?